# Windows BSOD error

Tags: windows, bsod

i just got this pc for my IT management degree, a Lenovo ideapad 110 core i7 8gb ram on windows 10. After running it and installing visual studio, virtual machine for linux and some other stuff all working well, and ater like a month of use it started to crash and giving me the blue screen of death as it is called. I looked online but there are many causes to this problem, i thought maybe if i showed the errors i am receiving someone could identify it.
     DRIVER IRQL NOT LESS OR EQUAL TO
     NO PAGES AVAILABLE
     DPC WATCHDOG VIOLATION
     SYSTEM THREAD EXCEPTION NOT HANDLED
Thank you for your time

Comment: [analyze the dumps with windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your system is generating minidump files on crash, and then open the crash dump with WhoCrashed http://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed

It'll do its best to tell you what software/driver is at fault.

Comment: How can i make sure if its generating these files?

Comment: System > Advanced System Settings > Advanced (tab) > Press 'Settings' under 'Startup and Recovery' whilst on that Advanced tab. Make sure 'Automatic memory dump' is set in the 'Write debugging information' drop down, and that a dump file path is specified.

Comment: What if it was a hardware problem?  Does it show as well?

Comment: I used that software and the results were that most problems are cause by : ntoskrnl.exe and others by : netwtw04.sys ... any information about what are those?

Comment: Network driver for sure https://communities.intel.com/thread/112883

Comment: I suspect my ram is corrupted (hardware issue) sonce it is much slower of a pc for a 8gb ram...

Comment: If you suspect RAM, then you need memtest in your life https://www.memtest86.com/